# Check if a shape is within the bounds of another shape using only x,y coords and shape area (2D)

Tags: xml, coordinates, xquery, collision-detection, area

So I have a XML database filled with data about different islands and lakes in the world and I want to select all lakes which have at least one island in them. Problem is that the only relevant data I have about each is their longitude, latitude and their total area.

Island XML example:

```
<island id="island-Svalbard" country="SVAX" sea="sea-ArcticOcean sea-Greenlandsea sea-NorwegianSea sea-BarentsSea">
  <name>Svalbard</name>
  <islands>Svalbard</islands>
  <area>39044</area>
  <latitude>78.9</latitude>
  <longitude>18.2</longitude>
  <elevation>1713</elevation>
</island>
```

Lake XML example:

```
<lake id="lake-LagunaCarbon" country="RA" type="saline">
  <name>Laguna del Carbón</name>
  <located country="RA" province="prov-Argentina-20"/>
  <area>9</area>
  <latitude>-49.58</latitude>
  <longitude>-68.35</longitude>
  <elevation>-105</elevation>
  <depth>0</depth>
</lake>
```

So how do I check if an island is within the bounds of a lake using only this information? Is it even possible?

Current (unfinished) Xquery:

```
let $doc := doc("mondial.xml")/mondial
let $lakes := $doc/lake
let $islands := $doc/island

let $lakesWithIslands := (
  for $l in $lakes
  let $lLong := $l/data(longitude)
  let $lLat := $l/data(latitude)
  let $lArea := $l/data(area)
    for $i in $islands
     let $iLong := $i/data(longitude)
     let $iLat := $i/data(latitude)
     let $iArea := $i/data(area)
     where (something)
  return $l
)

return $lakesWithIslands
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you cannot do that mathematically accurate, since you need an outline to determine if a point is within it. Why not calculate to distance/magnitude between the centers of the lakes and the islands and if it is below a certain threshold, it might very well be possible the the island in within the lake?

Comment: @philipp Yeah, that was my last resort. Hoping that there was a more accurate way to check this. The big problem is figuring out a reasonable threshold. I am also doing this as part of a school task and it states that no hard coding is permitted but I see no other option...

Comment: An area just does not include the necessary information for a »point in polygon« test. All you can do is use all the information you have: Same State, same elevation and so forth, plus some kind of  distance… If the lake has a great area the threshold might be bigger, and if the area of an island is larger/equal or close the one of a lake, I wouldn't count it as a hit as well…

Comment: @philipp Yeah ok. Seems I am gonna have to set a custom threshold even though I am not allowed to hard code. It seems my teachers didn't test the task themselves before handing them out. There is no way to do this without a little bit of hard coding it seems. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You can calculate the threshold based on the area of a lake, the relation of the radius to area of a circle might be a good idea: r = sqrt(Area/π^2) ??

Comment: @philipp Ah thanks! Didn't even think about that. Gonna try it!

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't allowed to use the `island/(@sea|@lake|@river)` attributes? They would tell you directly which bodies of water the island is in.

Comment: @LeoWörteler Every island only has a sea attribute. I don't see how that would help me, unless I am missing something.

Comment: If you are still using the document at https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial.xml, there are definitely results for the following query: `doc('mondial.xml')//island[@lake]`

Comment: @LeoWörteler OH MY GOD! Now I feel so stupid. I am new to both XQuery and BaseX. It never occured to me to do that! I was manually searching islands and checking for attributes. I am so dumb...

Comment: You can also query for the names of all attributes that occur in `island` elements: `distinct-values(doc('mondial.xml')//island/@*/node-name())` returns `('id', 'country', 'sea', 'type', 'river', 'lake')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there actually was a @lake attribute in the island elements that I could use to figure out which which lake an island was in and then use that to figure out which lakes that had islands in them. This was pointed out by @LeoWörteler in the comments. So my problem actually got a completely different solution.